# Business Software

Tags: software-recommendation, wine

I read that Ubuntu Linux will work "right out of the box" as an operating system for business software, Accounts Payable, Accounts Receivable, Inventory control, etc.

I use *Business Vision*, and am considering *Quick Books*, but both say the requirement is a version of Windows.

So what business solutions are available to use with Ubuntu?

Comment: Where did you read: _I read that Ubuntu Linux will work "right out of the box" as an operating system for business software, Accounts Payable, Accounts Receivable, Inventory control, etc_ ?

Comment: If you want to run a particular piece of software that requires Windows then you will have to install Windows.  There are free accounting packages for Linux that will run on Ubuntu. Take a look here: [UbuntuFinance](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuFinance) for a few.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of native book keeping software take a look at [GNUCash](http://www.gnucash.org/).

For inventory control I don't know any. If somebody knows any, edit or comment.

Answer (score 1):

## [Tryton](http://www.tryton.org/)

It is the core base of a complete business solution providing modularity, scalability and security.

> Currently, the main modules available for Tryton cover the following
>   fields of activity:
>
> - Accounting
> - Invoicing
> - Sale Management
> - Purchase Management
> - Analytic Accounting
> - Inventory Management
> - Manufacturing Resource Planning (MRP)
> - Project Management
> - Lead and Opportunity Management

It is programmed in Python and released under GPL 3.0; reliant on PostgreSQL. Available from the Software Centre.

## [SQL Ledger](http://www.sql-ledger.com/)

> SQL-Ledger® is a webbased ERP system which runs on any *NIX, Mac or
>   Windows platform.
>
> Accounting data is stored in a SQL database server, for the display
>   any text or GUI browser can be used.
>
> Built with freely available software so you are never locked in.
>
> Written in easy readable perl code.
>
> Intuitive interface so the learning curve is kept to a minimum. After
>   all who wants to spend hours learning a new program.
>
> Foreign languages supported out of the box, no special programs
>   required to make changes or add a new language.
>
> Installation is easy, it only takes a few minutes to install on most
>   systems.

Web-based and translated into many different languages. GPL 2.0, written in Perl and reliant on PostgreSQL.

## [xTuple PostBooks Edition](http://www.xtuple.com/postbooks)

> PostBooks is a full-featured, fully-integrated business management
>   system, the core of the award winning xTuple ERP Suite. Built with the
>   open source PostgreSQL database and the open source Qt framework for
>   C++, it provides the ultimate in power and flexibility for a range of
>   businesses and industries of any size.

Features:

> - Accounting (general ledger, accounts receivable and payable, bank reconciliation, financial reporting)
> - Sales (quotes, order entry, sales reporting, shipping)
> - CRM (universal address book, incident management, opportunity management, to-do lists, project management)
> - Purchasing (purchase orders, receiving, vendor reporting)
> - Product Definition (items, infinite-level bills of material)
> - Inventory and Distribution (multiple locations, other advanced warehouse features)
> - Light Manufacturing (work orders, strong support for make-to-order)
> - OpenRPT open source report writer

[Install instructions](http://www.xtuple.org/installing-postbooks-client-and-server).